# External Objects not supported in Force.com sites

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, externalobjects

(**Edit:** all of this is happening only in a Force.com site. The Lightning Web Component is not the source of the problem)
I'm trying to query an External Object inside @AuraEnabled method, but I'm getting the following error in LWC:

> sObject type 'public_accessories__x' is not supported.

The method works perfectly fine in Anonymous Apex.

So I've changed the return type of the method to a normal sObject:

Here's my method:

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<Accessories__c> getAccessories(String uid) {
    List<public_accessories__x> accsExt = [
            SELECT
                    id__c,
                    name__c,
                    type__c
            FROM public_accessories__x
            WHERE uid__c = :uid
            ORDER BY name__c ASC];

    List<Accessories__c> accs = new List<Accessories__c>();
    for (public_accessories__c__x accExt : accsExt) {
        accs.add(new Accessories__c(
                Name = accExt.name__c,
                Type__c = accExt.type__c
        ));
    }

    return accs;
}
```

But it still gives the same error! Apparently, if a method used in LWC queries an External Object in its body, then it doesn't work in LWC, even if the External Object is not the actual return type. Is that really the case and if yes, is it documented anywhere?

**Edit:** I did this in Developer Edition. I don't know if it's the same in a normal org because I don't have access to an org with external objects.

**Edit2:** OK, I've realized what actually causes this: all this time the LWC was embedded in a Force.com Site. I completely forgot about this fact. When the LWC is accessed normally from withing Salesforce, it works OK with external objects. But I still don't know why it doesn't work in Force.com Site. The Public Access profile has the permissions to the External Object.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the cacheable=true annotation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/apex   public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Phone, Email, Picture__c FROM Contact WHERE Picture__c != null LIMIT 10];
    }
}

Comment: @KevinHill Even with Cacheable=true it still doesn't work.

Comment: @KevinHill Hi, would you please be able to look at this issue again? I tried adding Cacheable=true but it didn't cause the error to go away. I also verified that it throws the same error when invoked from Aura Component. So it may be an issue with AuraEnabled methods in general. And one more thing: this is in Developer Edition.

Comment: There is a one help doc saying that we have to disable "High Data Volume" option for use in lightning. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_considerations_lex.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks @ManjotSingh, good to know that. Unfortunately, it's already disabled in my External Data Source. I've even enabled and disabled again just in case, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What you are using for external object oDATA or custom apex?

Comment: @ManjotSingh I use Salesforce Connect: OData 4.0. This is Heroku free tier, configured using recommended, standard extension.

Comment: Actually I tried using Odata services given in trailhead module.. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_setup... it is working fine with aura components... so I don't think this is a lightning issue or developer org issue... This might be issue with Odata service you have implemented

Comment: Hi @mmm321321, just to chip in here, is there per user authentication set up for the external object adapter? Do you have any authentication set up? I'm wondering if that is restricting access to the external object.